# How do I fix Assembly C# load fail?

Tags: c#

In Visual Studio I get this output:

> The project file could not be loaded. An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 72, position 59.  C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BlakeneyBrian_CustomNPC&ItemTool\Unity Project\Assembly-CSharp.csproj

I believe the & symbol is the issue but if I change the name of the file I lose everything else in it.  This file is attached to numerous different projects and I can't lose those projects but it is not working in my current project.  How do I fix this?  I have been searching for a solution but can't find exactly what I need.

In Unity I get this compile error:

> Assets/4-NavAgent_Best/Scripts/NavAgentStateMachine_Best.cs(22,18): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PauseState' could not be found. Are you missing 'UnityEditor' using directive?

It is a class assignment and I have built the code exactly as I was told but it won't run.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the UnityEditor namespace within a normal folder. To use the UnityEditor you would have to have the script in an editor folder. `Assets/Editor/` for example.

But UnityEditor scripts won't include in the final build.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html